# Dell laptop battery backup 1.30 hours only with Ubuntu 12.04. How can the battery backup be increased?

Tags: nvidia, dell, intel-graphics, backup, battery

Dell laptop 
Model: N5110 (Inspiron 15R)
Display: 15.6" 
Battery: 6 cell 
Graphics: NVidia GeForce 525M 1GB (No driver for Ubuntu), Working on Intel Graphics 1GB 
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) 64 bit 
 
Dell laptop battery backup 1.30 hours only with Ubuntu 12.04. How can the battery backup be increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the reason turned out to be that the graphic card was always ON.

What you need to do is to install `bumblebee` which turns off your graphic card. You can still use it when you need.

**Installing Bumblebee**

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

- Reboot or re-login.

For more information, you can visit the [Ubuntu BumbleBee Wiki Page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).

Answer (score 0):

Try the jupiter applet, play around with some settings and see if it helps

Press Ctrl-Alt-t, terminal will pop up; type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

enter password (you won't see it as you type, that's normal), confirm adding the repo, then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jupiter
sudo jupiter
```

click the "lightning bolt" that appears on the panel, play around with some settings, ie set Performance to "Power on demand" or "Power saving". Reboot.